# When open new page Flutter UI Update delayed with Getx in StateLessWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I want use this timer funtion in the statelessWidget.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      controller.statAnimation();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            ATexts.welcomeTo,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Obx(() {
              return AnimatedPositioned(
                top: AHelperFunctions.screenHeight() * .1,
                left: controller.isAnimation.value
                    ? AHelperFunctions.screenWidth() * .25
                    : -AHelperFunctions.screenWidth() * .5,
                width: AHelperFunctions.screenWidth() * .5,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                child: Image.asset(AImages.googleLogo),
              );
            }),
```

we can update state in StateLessWidget using getX but i want use StatFullWidget only for delay.

Answer (score 0):

You have an animation with [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html), the correct way is to use a `StatefulWidget`. No need to convert to `StatelessWidget`.

Another option is to use `HookWidget` from the [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) package.